# Перевод систем счисления. Выход за пределы диапазона

Tags: c

Дано число в системе счисления по основанию А. Нужно перевести его в систему по основанию А в степени В.

```
Input
```

Со стандартного устройства ввода вводятся натуральные числа A,B и число L-длина записи числа в системе счисления по основанию А. Гарантируется, что L кратно B и не превышает 10000.

 Во второй строке содержится L-цифр- исходное число в системе счисления с основанием А. А в степени В не превышает 36

```
Output
```

Нужно выдать на стандартное устройство вывода исходное число в системе счисления по основанию A в степени В.

```
Sample input

2 4 32
00111011100101110110011011001111

Sample Output
3B9766CF
```

Мой код:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int RecVozvrat(int a)
{
    switch (a) {
    case 10: return 'A';
    case 11: return 'B';
    case 12: return 'C';
    case 13: return 'D';
    case 14: return 'E';
    case 15: return 'F';
    case 16: return 'G';
    case 17: return 'H';
    case 18: return 'I';
    case 19: return 'J';
    case 20: return 'K';
    case 21: return 'L';
    case 22: return 'M';
    case 23: return 'N';
    case 24: return 'O';
    case 25: return 'P';
    case 26: return 'Q';
    case 27: return 'R';
    case 28: return 'S';
    case 29: return 'T';
    case 30: return 'U';
    case 31: return 'V';
    case 32: return 'W';
    case 33: return 'X';
    case 34: return 'Y';
    case 35: return 'Z';
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a, b, l, ab, i, j, l1;
    unsigned long int res, v, res1, res2;
    char c[10000], c1[10000];

    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &l);  // Ввод системы, степени и длины числа
    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++) {   // Ввод числа
        c[i] = getchar();
    }
    l1 = l - 1;
    ab = pow(a, b);
    res = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {  // Перевод в 10 систему счисления
        v = c[i] & 0x0F;
        if (v > 0) {
            v = v * pow(a, l1);
            l1--;
            res = res + v;
        }
        else l1--;
    }
    i = 0;
    if (ab > 9) {    // перевод в систему счисления больше 10
        while (res > ab) {
            res1 = res / ab;
            res2 = res % ab;
            res = res1;
            if (res2 > 9) c1[i] = RecVozvrat(res2);
            else c1[i] = res2 | 0x30;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else while (res > ab) { // перевод в систему счисления меньше 10
        res1 = res / ab;
        res2 = res % ab;
        res = res1;
        c1[i] = res2 | 0x30;
        i++;
    }

    if (res > 9) c1[i] = RecVozvrat(res);
    else c1[i] = res | 0x30;
    if (i % 2 != 0)v = i / 2 + 1;
    else v = i / 2;
    l1 = i;
    for (j = 0; j < v; j++) {    // Разворачиваем число
        c[j] = c1[j];
        c1[j] = c1[i];
        c1[i] = c[j];
        i--;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= l1; j++)  // Вывод ответа
        printf("%c", c1[j]);
}
```

Числа в 10 системе выходит за диапазон типа данных unsigned long int. Как сделать так, чтобы программа работала и за диапазоном

Comment: Используйте массивы. По сути тут нужна базовая реализация длинной арифметики.

Comment: Не подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Намек. Нет, даже так: **НАМЁК**. Если вам дано число в системе счисления 2, то число в системе счисления 16, скажем — т.е. 2 в степени 4 — получается путем сбора тетрад (по четыре знака двоичных) и их преобразования в 16-ричную цифру. У вас значения из системы счисления A надо перевести в систему счисления A в степени B. Ничего не напоминает? И не нужны никакие длинные арифметики! Дайте, кстати, URL проверялки — тогда попробую код набросать...